# Using multiple conditions in Django's Case When expressions

Tags: python, django, django-orm

As per the Django documentation, its possible to use multiple conditions with the When clause.

```py
When(
    registered_on__gt=date(2014, 1, 1),
    registered_on__lt=date(2015, 1, 1),
    then='account_type'
)
```

However, I am unable to use the same when using the Case clause.

```py
Case(
    When(
        registered_on__gt=date(2014, 1, 1),
        registered_on__lt=date(2015, 1, 1), 
        then='account_type'
    ),
    default='default'
)
```

I end up getting the following error:

`TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'then'`

Is there some way I can achieve this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe [Q expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) can help. Try this:

```py
Case(
    When(
        Q(registered_on__gt=date(2014, 1, 1)) & Q(registered_on__lt=date(2015, 1, 1)),
        then='account_type'
    ),
    default='default'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) of Case expression, each `When` expression in the `Case` class has its own `then` parameters, and instead of put all the condition in only one parameter `When`, I think maybe you should extract into 2 `When` expressions, with 2 separate then parameters, as below:

```
    Case(
         When(
            registered_on__gt=date(2014, 1, 1),
            then = 'account_type',
         ),
         When(
            registered_on__lt=date(2015, 1, 1),
            then = 'account_type',
         ),
         default='default'
    )
```

Hope it helps. If anything else is unclear please let me know.
Cheer!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work. When `registered_on = date(2016, 1, 1)`, I would like the value to be `default`. In case of your answer, the first condition would be satisfied since Django stops processing the When statements as soon as one of them is true.

Comment: To be very clear about why this answer won't cover the case: this would work for an or, but the question was in terms of an and.  Both conditions must be met; not just one or the other.

Comment: How can generate When in loop such as for, use it in Case after that?